# Open the Django project on git in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, django, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Django project on git repository. I would like to open this project with Visual Studio 2015 and continue. There is no "Python" option list of project types in the Create Project from Existing Code Files Wizard window.

What should I do to have the python option listed?

Or

How to open this project?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Python Tools for VS.
https://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/

Comment: Thanks Allee Clark. But Python Tools 2.2.6 for Visual Studio 2015 is already installed. I'm also continuing to write c# at the same time. So I should be able to work in visual studio.

Comment: I found. If you already have existing Python code, you can easily create a new project without having to move it around. In the New Project window select "From Existing Python Code". https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Projects#create-project-from-existing-files.